# protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter blank screenshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, protractor, jasmine2.0

Protractor config file have 2 reporting custom report for logging and other one is **protractor-
jasmine2-screenshot-reporte**r. Screenshot png is generate but blank white screen only dispalyed.
Below code for conf.js.

```
let HtmlScreenshotReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter');
let DateFormat = require('../utils/date-format').DateFormat;

let ReportGenerator = require('../utils/customReport').ReportGenerator;
let reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator({
dest: '/../reports/',
filename: 'CoHubReport',
reportTitle: 'CoHub Automation Suite',
cssPath: './../utils/reportUtil/customReport-styles.css',
jsPath: './../utils/reportUtil/reportUtil.js'
    });

let reporter = new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
showConfiguration: false,
captureOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
takeScreenshots: true,
userCss: './../../utils/report-styles.css',
dest: './../reports',
filename: 'CoHub_Report_' + DateFormat(new Date(), "yyyymmdd") + '.html',
reportTitle: "Co Hub Report :" + DateFormat(new Date(), "mm-dd-yyyy HH:MM"),
cleanDestination: false,
consolidateAll: false
});

exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

//   sauceUser: "0000",
//  sauceKey: "00000",

restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
getPageTimeout: 80000,
allScriptsTimeout: 50000000,

specs: [
         './pagecheck/settings/configavo-spec.js',
    // './pagecheck/ant/antent-spec.js',
],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000000,
    isVerbose: true
},

multiCapabilities: [
   
    {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        version: 'latest',
        platform: 'Windows 10',
        name: "chrome-tests",
        shardTestFiles: true,
        sequential: true,
        maxInstances: 3
    }
],

framework: 'jasmine2',
beforeLaunch: function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter.beforeLaunch(resolve);
    });
},
onPrepare: function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(reporter);

    beforeEach(function () {

        reportGenerator.initiate();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        reportGenerator.finalize();
    });
},
afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
}
};
```

Also, can require screenshot to be attached to html report. we have limitation to use other reporting within the project, please dont recommend other reporting to use.

Comment: i'd start with a simple code instead of debugging all at once. Try this simple config from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter which doesn't have custom css, templates etc. If that still doesn't work, then the problem is unlikely in the reporter and is in your app.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
exports.config {
   ...
   noGlobals: false,
   ...
}
```

Setting it to `false` allow to use default globals: 'protractor', 'browser', '$', '$$', 'element', 'by'. These also exist as properties of the protractor namespace: 'protractor.browser', 'protractor.$', 'protractor.$$', 'protractor.element', 'protractor.by', and 'protractor.By'.

When no globals is set to true, the only available global variable will be 'protractor' [link](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api-overview#global-variables)

Comment: NoGlobals: false, is not helping still getting same blank screenshot.